# Help me "get" Object Orientated PHP

Tags: php

I'm could probably pass as a PHP developer, but I just don't "get" the object orientated side and it's high time I sorted it out.

In the code snippet I have some code I've written to pull some info from a mongoDB. I realised I've used some classes in there but I haven't constructed any - they're just what the MongoDB driver provides.
In the foreach loop I have some variables that are printed out from the MongoDB. I'd like to make that foreach loop a class so that I can call something like:

```
print->Environment
print->Architecture
```

which makes it nice and clean and simple. I figure if someone can help me create a class from something I've already written it might help me "get" classes and objects. All help gratefully considered.

Consider the following:

```
$gethost=$_GET['q'];
try {
  // open connection to MongoDB server
  $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

  // access database
  $db = $conn->factdb;

  //authenticate
  $db->authenticate('username','password');

  // access collection
  $collection = $db->hosts;

  // define what to find
  $host = array(
        'host' => $gethost
);
  // disconnect from server
  $conn->close();
} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
  die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
} catch (MongoException $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

 $cursor = $collection->find($host);
  foreach ($cursor as $value) {
          echo '<tr><td><b>Environment</b></td><td>'.$value['facter']['environment']['value'].'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['facter']['environment']['created_at']).'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['facter']['environment']['updated_at']).'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td><b>FQDN</b></td><td>'.$value['facter']['fqdn']['value'].'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['facter']['fqdn']['created_at']).'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['facter']['fqdn']['updated_at']).'</td></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td><b>Model</b></td><td>'.$value['allocations']['model']['value'].'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['allocations']['model']['created_at']).'</td><td>'.date("M j Y",$value['allocations']['model']['updated_at']).'</td></tr>';   
}
```

Comment: Your code is object-BASED programming. Actual OOP programming involves creating brand new objects from the ground up, or extending/inheriting other objects.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me as you have absolutely no knowledge of OOP (apart from using `->` to access properties). Don't worry, the basics are not too hard to learn. You should start with the OOP chapter from [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Good luck,
Alin

Comment: @MattB If you want to skip the contents and introduction :). Lazy reader.

Comment: I learned the basics of OOP by taking an introductory Java course.  After that, OOP in PHP made a lot of sense, especially after working with CodeIgniter for a few website applications.

Comment: @Marc Audet Still... Humor me and study The PHP Manual as well. I promise you won't regret it. It's a very pleasant lecture.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru I just took a look at the PHP Manual, well worth reading it to refresh concepts learned some time ago.  Thanks!

Comment: I have read and read the PHP manual and just can't get my head around it. The problem is that I don't want to create classes with "foo" and "bar" in there I want to create real classes I can work with.

Comment: @Frap You've read the OOP chapter in one hour? Multiple times even? I'm sorry to tell you this, my friend, but I don't believe you. You appear lazy. If you want to be able to code you also need to study.

Comment: @Alin you think I meant today? I've read it in the past, and again, will stress I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you would probably want

```
$Environment->print()
$Architecture->print()
```

not

```
print->Environment
print->Architecture
```

Second unless we know more about Environment and Architecture data and how it is used we will not be able to create a usable class for you.

Third by looking at how objects and classes are implemented you will not "get" OOP, you should learn about Encapsulation, Inheritance, Abstraction etc..  And then worry about implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to start somewhere and classes and objects are a place to start. I can worry about inheritance etc once I've got the basics down.

Comment: Additionally I'd like print-> Architecture to take a variable defined by 

$value['facter']['environment']['value'] from the foreach loop and print it inside <td> tags essentially.

$value is defined by 
$cursor = $collection->find($host);
  foreach ($cursor as $value) {
}

essentially I want a "print" (or environment) class that has functions within that gets the values of array $value['factor']['environment']['value'] (replace environment with array values where necessary

Comment: @Frap there is **absolutely no point** in using objects if you will not use any of the fundamental concepts of OOP. Stick with functional programming until you understand *why* you need objects. Just start with reading on oop on wikipedia. Then when you understand what benifits you will get from using objects, you can start exploring ways to implement them. Currently the functionality you want to achieve (as described in your second comment) **should not** be implemented using objects.